# pushPage can't work - Onsen monaca phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui, monaca

JS

```
app.controller('categoryController', function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/public/api/v1/category').success(function(response){
        $scope.myCategory = response.data;
    });

    $scope.showSubCategory = function(index) {
        var selectedItem = $scope.myCategory[index];
        var options = { animation: 'slide' };

        $scope.myCategory.selectedItem = selectedItem;

        $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('subcategory.html', options, {name : selectedItem.name}); 
    };
});
```

HTML/Angular/Onsen

```
  <ons-navigator>
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Home</div>
            <div class="right">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="fa-search"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>


        <ons-list ng-controller="categoryController" id="category-lists">
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item" ng-repeat="item in myCategory" ng-click="showSubCategory($index)">
                <ons-row>
                    {{item.name}}
                </ons-row>                          
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>

    </ons-page>   
  </ons-navigator>
```

Error

TypeError: Cannot call method 'pushPage' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.showSubCategory (file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/app.js:16:27)
    at file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1439:30512
    at file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1448:18904
    at Scope.$eval (file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1437:28127)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1437:28433)
    at HTMLElement.listener (file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1448:18886)
    at HTMLElement.eventHandler (file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1434:29261)
    at FastClick.sendClick (file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1441:13284)
    at FastClick.onTouchEnd (file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1441:17447)
    at HTMLBodyElement. (file:///data/data/com.example.helloworld/files/projects/cloud/558d3c277e2193c742d69fea/www/components/loader.js:1441:10005)

Hi, I have use monaca.pushPage(subcategory.html, .....) and no error but can't move to subcategory.html page.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`ons` variable does not store the navigators anymore. You must use `var` attribute in the navigator and give it a name to call it afterwards. For example:

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
    ...
</ons-navigator>
```

And then use it with `myNavigator.pushPage(...)`. More info here: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html

Hope it helps!